# secure file copy (scp) back and forth from remote line to Windows

Tags: linux, ssh, csv, scp

Need to learn more about `scp` but I was able to transfer an entire directory (`registry_configs`) of CSV files from a remote linux machine (`geb@192.168.0.106`) to my Windows 10 environment with this:

```
scp -r geb@192.168.0.106:/var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs/ C:\Users\bbartling\Desktop\testBenchVolttronMods
```

I have one modified CSV file I am trying to transfer back to the remote Linux instance, but I have something wrong. I keep getting a perimission denied error even with the same password I used to transfer the directory initially.

```
scp C:\Users\bbartling\Desktop\testBenchVolttronMods\registry_configs\29.csv geb@192.168.0.106:/var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs
```

This will give me an error:

```
scp: /var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs/29.csv: Permission denied
```

Any tips to try greatly appreciated. Could someone also show me how to transfer back an entire directory from my Windows 10 environment back to the Linux machine? This would almost be better than an individual file, where I could just transfer back the entire `registry_configs` directory overwrite all existing files on the Linux machine.

Comment: You probably have read permissions but not write permissions on that file on the remote host. Get write permissions and that should be fine.

Comment: Ok so I have this correct, get write permission on the remote linux host?

Comment: In here https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions

Comment: `chmod -rwx directoryname` to remove permissions?

Comment: It depends who is the owner of the file. If it is you, you can, on the remote host, execute: `chmod u+w /var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs/29.csv` (`u` is for user, `o` for others, so don't use `o`)

Comment: Yes I am the owner of both machines and files. But the windows & Linux usernames are different

Comment: Could I use this to change the permissions for the entire `registry_configs` directory? `chmod u+w /var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs`

Comment: A directory is not the same as the files it contains. I suspect you want to change the permissions for all those files. In which case you should either use your shell's glob feature `chmod u+w /var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs/*` or execute `chmod` recursively: `chmod -R u+w /var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs`. Note that this last solution will change the permissions on that directory and ALL the elements in it, including any directories, their content, and so on. So depending on what is in your directory, you might want to be careful with that.

Comment: Would you know how I could get around this? `chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs/29.csv': Operation not permitted`

Comment: For some reason I cant even `nano` the CSV file on the Linux machine

Comment: actually `sudo nano` works

Comment: `sudo` without any other parameter will (by default) grant you the root rights. So, you will have the highest privileges on the machine. Of course this will work. For editing, it is not recommended. You *will*, however, need it for changing the permissions: `sudo chmod u+w /var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs/29.csv`.

Comment: why not recommended? Sorry still learning. This worked if you wanted to post an answer `sudo chmod -R u+w /var/lib/volttron/scripts/bacnet/registry_configs` to make my entire directory writeable. Thanks for this....

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was editing my comment to make it easier to understand. Hope everything is clear now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121331/discussion-between-7heo-tk-and-henryhub).